# Add text labels in photos

Tags: photos, android-11, editing

In Android 11 (Samsung Galaxy A20):

When editing a photo using the OOTB Gallery/photo editing functionality, is there a way to add text labels in a photo?

Like this (label added in MS Paint):

[image]

Comment: If OOTB means Out Of The Box, there is no standard gallery app as manufacturers can change code/features (fonts/colors/filters/etc.). Without knowing which device you have, you may be served better by finding and installing an app that fits your needs.

Comment: There are photo editor apps like [Snapseed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed) which offer adding text to an image if that is what you are searching for.